# Can Anyone Tell Me Why This Text Is Not Centering In Android Studio?

Tags: android, layout

I'm attempting to align the text as you would expect to see if you were in a word pad and set your alignment to center, the middle of each line would be in the center of the screen and each margin to the left and right would be equidistant. However, using gravity does not appear to be working as the text is still starting from the left. Could someone shed light as to why? Here's the xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#111111"
    tools:context="eqlogic.annswingsandthings.AboutUs">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chalkBoard"
        android:src="@drawable/ann_chalkboard_img"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:text="@string/AboutUsText"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="false" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are not setting the gravity. (hint: the attribute you are looking for is named `gravity`)

Comment: @njzk2 - Yeah, that was a stupid mistake. I had layout_gravity in my head. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the gravity, use:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Full tag:

```
<TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:text="@string/AboutUsText"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Comment: Wow, my mistake. For some reason I had layout_gravity in my head. Thanks Brother. Will select as answer when time limit allows.

Answer (score 1):

Set also `android:gravity` parameter in `ScrollView` to `center`.

For testing the effects of different layout parameters I recommend to use different background color for every element, so you can see how your layout changes with parameters like gravity, layout_gravity or others.

Answer (score 0):

Make your **layout_width** be *fill_parent* and use **gravity** instead of **layout_gravity**:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:text="@string/AboutUsText"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollview parameters Android:layout_width="match_parent" and Android:gravity="center".